# Why I got this massage "too few parameters. expected 1"? in MS Access

Tags: query-string

My database has:
Table name “Books”
Query name “BooksQMiss”
Form name “100” which has a combo name “Combo0”

The query has the following fields:
Field name "Serial"
Field name “Section”

I use the below module to find the gaps in field "Serial" with a criteria inserted in “Section” field:
[Forms]![100]![Combo0]

[Query name “BooksQMiss”](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtaIn.jpg)

```
Function FindGaps()
Dim mydb As Database
Dim mytbl As Recordset
Dim mytbl2 As Recordset
Dim lastnum As Integer
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE Lost_Number.* FROM Lost_Number;"
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
Set mydb = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).Databases(0)
Set mytbl = mydb.OpenRecordset("BooksQMiss") ' The problem is here
Set mytbl2 = mydb.OpenRecordset("Lost_number")
With mytbl
  .MoveFirst
  lastnum = 1
  Do Until .EOF
    If !Serial - lastnum >= 1 Then

      Do
         If mytbl!Serial - lastnum = 0 Then Exit Do
            With mytbl2
                .AddNew
                !missing = lastnum
            .Update
            End With
         lastnum = lastnum + 1
      Loop
      lastnum = lastnum + 1
      .MoveNext
    Else
      lastnum = !Serial + 1
      .MoveNext
    End If
  Loop
End With
mytbl.Close
mytbl2.Close
Set mytbl = Nothing
Set mytbl2 = Nothing
Set mydb = Nothing

DoCmd.OpenForm "frm-Lost_Number", acNormal, "", "", , acNormal

End Function
```

My question is why I got this massage "too few parameters. expected 1"?

Anyone can help!
Thank you.